# How to allow Active Directory authenticated users use Nagios web interface?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, active-directory, nagios, httpd

I have put `.htaccess` files in the Nagios html root and CGI root directories, so in order to get access to the web interface, the users needs a valid Active Directory account.

The problem I have is in `/etc/nagios/cgi.cfg` which says

```
use_authentication=1

authorized_for_system_information=nagiosadmin
authorized_for_configuration_information=nagiosadmin
authorized_for_system_commands=nagiosadmin
authorized_for_all_services=nagiosadmin
authorized_for_all_hosts=nagiosadmin
authorized_for_all_service_commands=nagiosadmin
authorized_for_all_host_commands=nagiosadmin
```

Setting `use_authentication=0` "solves" the problem, but I have read

> Also, disabling authentication causes all sorts of things to not work 
>   because the programmers don't want to be responsible for what happens
>   It's best to use authentication and then set it up correctly ;-)

so I am not too keen on that.

It should be possible to replace `nagiosadmin` with a group according to

> Basically all of these "authorized_for_" stuff is to permit 
>   "administrative" users to access the system.
>
> One convenience that they don't tell you is that you can put  group
>   names instead of user accounts, so if you've got an IT Admin group
>   defined, put that instead of all of the members of the group

**Question**

How do I define such group when the users authenticate through htaccess with Apache's
`mod_authz_ldap.so`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved the problem.

```
sed -i 's/nagiosadmin/\*/g' /etc/nagios/cgi.cfg
sed -i 's/#default_user_name=guest/default_user_name=guest/g' /etc/nagios/cgi.cfg
```